# A mysterious square

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am a square, the youngest I can be, but not a baby.
>   but not the multiplied by one.
>   I'm not a mishearing of no.
>   My friends call me strange.
>   But, I am not only one.
>   What am I?

Complete explanation of main riddle for acceptance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that you are:

> -1

I am a square, the youngest I can be, but not a baby.

> -1 = *i* ^ 2, where *i* is the [unit imaginary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).
>  
>  
>  The 'not a baby' rules out zero, based on the4kman's answer and user_194421's subsequent update to the question.

but not the multiplied by one.

> This rules out 1 (or +1) as being the square

I'm not a mishearing of no.

> This rules out 0 ("oh") and 4.

When my friends asked me, "What is your area?", I said I have none.

> Positive squares can be considered as the representation of an area, whereas -1 cannot.

They called me strange as a result.

> This does not fit in with conventional (physical) examples of numbers, hence is strange (and the associated numbers are therefore called complex numbers).

But, I am not only one.

> Because you are *minus* one.

What am I?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> 0?

I am a square, the youngest I can be

> Zero is the smallest non-negative number, and the square of 0.

but not the multiplied by one

> Zero is not the square of 1.

I'm not a mishearing of no

> You are not "four".

When my friends asked me, "What is your area?", I said I have none

> A square with sides of 0 has an area of 0.

They called me strange as a result

> If you get 0 as a result, it's unusual (you might've been miscalculated something, e.g. multiplied something with 0).

But, I am not only one

> You are not one (since you are 0).

Comment: How is "four" a "mishearing of no"? The fact that your answer isn't 4 is irrelevant. What about "Oh"?

Comment: *nine* sounds like *nein*